# OpenCL scan code

Tags: opencl, nvidia, prefix-sum

I'm looking for a fast implementation of scan(prefixsum) in OpenCL. The best thing that I found is in the Nvidia SDK but it's old(2010).
Does anyone know any other implementation of Scan in OpenCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several open-source implementations of scan operation in OpenCL:

- [CLOGS](http://clogs.sourceforge.net/), a library for higher-level operations on top of the OpenCL C++ API.
- [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/boostorg/compute), a C++ GPU Computing Library for OpenCL.
- [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl), a C++ vector expression template library for OpenCL/CUDA.
- [Bolt](https://github.com/HSA-Libraries/Bolt), a C++ template library optimized for GPUs.

The author of CLOGS wrote a [paper](http://www.brucemerry.org.za/_downloads/ssbench-preprint.pdf) comparing performance of scan (and sort) operations in these implementations.

Answer (score 0):

if your device supports 2.0 then, use builtin operations for that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394920/4877550

http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/11/17/opencl-2-0-device-enqueue/

Comment: Built-in operations are limited to one workgroup (a few dozen threads)